# I need help to reject the dropdown selection

Tags: google-apps-script

I have  a google sheet to log my teammates' work log using app script

I need help to reject the dropdown selection in the "Status" column as below

If the "Start date"  has value and a user selects "In-progress"

If the "Closed date" has value and the user select "Completed"

The "Start date" & "Closed date" values are generated based on the "Status" column drop-down selection of "In-progress"  &   "Completed"

The rest of the status should be able to change based on users requirement

**Sheet link** https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/104zXXM3bEAZVE-CV2_Mit55ZeXEuZJWpFI1ia622T3A/edit#gid=249066000

**Script Link** https://script.google.com/u/0/home/projects/11W7D3mbtDM_yRHlPsneOwclaM0APIQq13stIwWRtnohZUGTkHKuDSw7L/edit

Comment: Hey do you mean that you want to set like a milestone based system? Once they selected "in progress" it should not be a selection in the future?

Comment: Hey @LucasLui888 yes

Comment: hey @ian, very clear. I have provided my suggestion in the answer below and also implemented the code into your sheet. Further explanation in my answer

Comment: Hey @LucasLui888

Thank you for your time :)
Can we set the same validation based on row, I think it's working based on column

Comment: Hey yeap, just got to the `.getRange()` section to change where you want it to affect, currently I chose the whole of Col C

Comment: Try it out and let me know if it has helped solved the problem you are facing :)

Comment: Hi @LucasLui888

Thanks again I tried your suggestion but not sure what I am missing here  

What I am trying to accomplish here is if a user select "In-progress" in cell C1 the drop down shouldn't show  "In-progress" in cell C1 but it should be shown in the rest of the C column cells until the  the user select "In-progress"

But now if I select  "In-progress" in cell C1 the "In-progress" value is not shown in the drop down below C1 cells

Comment: Hey Ian, I added a bit more specificity to the code and tried it now it should work. Please find the new code in my edited answet.

Comment: Unfortunately you might want to partner that with a time driven factor because currently you have set it onedit and what it does is unless there is someone else making changes the new round the "In-progress" for the latest one will still be available

Comment: So u need two triggers, an onedit and a time driven for every minute to check the cells

Comment: Hey was the new suggestion able to help?

Comment: Hey @LucasLui888 sorry for the late response this is perfect, thank you for your time and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey would recommend using a **forEach** loop to read every line of Col F basically since your code already sets in the date and time when they first choose "In progress". So if its has started (Col F filled), then the ***NEW DATA VALIDATION*** will be set into Col C.

```
function dropdown(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const data = ss.getDataRange().getValues()
  var oldvalidation = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['In-progress','Continue','Pause','Completed'], true).build();
  var newvalidation = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['Continue','Pause','Completed'], true).build();

//Going down each row of Col F, if the cell is empty then skip, else if its filled (means started) then "in progress" milestone not included into new data validation
  data.forEach(function(row,col){
    if (col == "") return;
    if (row[5] != "")
    {
      ss.getRange(col+1,3).setDataValidation(newvalidation); //set new validation 
    }

    else
    {
      ss.getRange(col+1,3).setDataValidation(oldvalidation); //set new validation 
    }
});
}
```

[image: Time driven every min]

References:

1. https://spreadsheet.dev/foreach-loop-in-apps-script
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJUVrhmv3A8